# Downloading data directly onto Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, download

Is there a way to download external files (.tiff or .csv for example) directly onto my earth engine account?  Currently, to import external files, I have to download it first onto  my own computer, then upload it to the GEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately with external files you should download to your computer and import as you are doing currently. If you need some guidance on importing raster and table data, these tutorials will help:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/importing

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_upload